# One thread stopping too early regardless of CyclicBarrier

Tags: java, multithreading, socketchannel, cyclicbarrier

I am aware of the fact that the following code may seem vulgar, but I am new to these things and just tried everything in order to get it to work..

Problem: Even though I am using (possible in a wrong way) a CyclicBarrier, one - and seems to always be the same - thread stops too soon and prints out his vector, leaving 1 out of 11 of those "Incoming connection" messages absent. There is probably something terribly wrong with the last iteration of my loop, but I can't seem to find what exactly.. Now the program just loops waiting to process the last connection.

```
public class VectorClockClient implements Runnable {
/*
 * Attributes
 */

/*
 * The client number is store to provide fast
 * array access when, for example, a thread's own
 * clock simply needs to be incremented.
 */
private int clientNumber;
private File configFile, inputFile;
int[] vectorClock;

/*
 * Constructor
 * @param
 * - File config
 * - int line
 * - File input
 * - int clients
 */
public VectorClockClient(File config, int line, File input, int clients) {
    /*
     * Make sure that File handles aren't null and that
     * the line number is valid.
     */
    if (config != null && line >= 0 && input != null) {
        configFile = config;
        inputFile = input;
        clientNumber = line;
        /*
         * Set the array size to the number of lines found in the
         * config file and initialize with zero values.
         */
        vectorClock = new int[clients];
        for (int i = 0; i < vectorClock.length; i++) {
            vectorClock[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

private int parsePort() {
    int returnable = 0;
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(configFile.getName());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < clientNumber + 1; i++) {
            strLine = br.readLine();
        }
        String[] tokens = strLine.split(" ");
        returnable = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("[" + clientNumber + "] returned with " + returnable + ".");
    return returnable;
}

private int parsePort(int client) {
    int returnable = 0;
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(configFile.getName());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < client; i++) {
            strLine = br.readLine();
        }
        String[] tokens = strLine.split(" ");
        returnable = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnable;
}

private int parseAction(String s) {
    int returnable = -1;
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(configFile.getName());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String[] tokens = s.split(" ");
        if (!(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) == this.clientNumber + 1)) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            if (tokens[1].equals("L")) {
                vectorClock[clientNumber] += Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            }
            else {
                returnable = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnable;
}

/*
 * Do the actual work.
 */
public void run() {
    try {
        InitClients.barrier.await();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    int port = parsePort();
    String hostname = "localhost";
    String strLine;
    ServerSocketChannel ssc;
    SocketChannel sc;
    FileInputStream fstream;
    DataInputStream in;
    BufferedReader br;
    boolean eof = false;
    try {
        ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        ssc.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port));
        ssc.configureBlocking(false);
        fstream = new FileInputStream("input_vector.txt");
        in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        try {
            InitClients.barrier.await();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        while (true && (eof == false)) {
            sc = ssc.accept();

            if (sc == null) {
                if ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    int result = parseAction(strLine);
                    if (result >= 0) {
                        //System.out.println("[" + (clientNumber + 1)
                        //+ "] Send a message to " + result + ".");
                        try {
                            SocketChannel client = SocketChannel.open();
                            client.configureBlocking(true);
                            client.connect(
                                    new InetSocketAddress("localhost",
                                    parsePort(result)));
                            //ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(32);
                            //buf.put((byte)0xFF);
                            //buf.flip();
                            //vectorClock[clientNumber] += 1;
                            //int numBytesWritten = client.write(buf);
                            String obj = Integer.toString(clientNumber+1);
                            ObjectOutputStream oos = new 
                                    ObjectOutputStream(
                                    client.socket().getOutputStream());
                            oos.writeObject(obj);
                            oos.close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    eof = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new 
                        ObjectInputStream(sc.socket().getInputStream());
                String clientNumberString = (String)ois.readObject();
                System.out.println("At {Client[" + (clientNumber + 1)
                        + "]}Incoming connection from: "
                        + sc.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress()
                        + " from {Client[" + clientNumberString + "]}");
                sc.close();
            }
            try {
                InitClients.barrier.await();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    printVector();
}

private void printVector() {
    System.out.print("{Client[" + (clientNumber + 1) + "]}{");
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorClock.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(vectorClock[i] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println("}");
}
```

}

To clarify, here are the formats of the files used. Config contains hostnames and ports used by clients that are threads and input file's rows mean either "this client sends a message to that client" or "this client increments his logical clock by some constant value".

1 M 2 (M means sending a message)
2 M 3
3 M 4
2 L 7 (L means incrementing clock)
2 M 1
 ...

127.0.0.1 9000
127.0.0.1 9001
127.0.0.1 9002
127.0.0.1 9003
    ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at the logic related to when you are expecting an incoming socket connection.  From your question it looks like you expect a certain number of incoming socket connections (potentially an incoming connection after every outgoing message?).  Since you are using non-blocking I/O on the incoming socket it is always possible that your while statement loops before an incoming socket could be established.  As a result, a thread would be able to continue and read the next line from the file without receiving a connection.  Since your end state is reached once the end of the file is reached, it is possible that you may miss an incoming socket connection.

I would add some simple print outs that displays when you read from the file, when you send a message and when you receive an incoming connection.  That should quickly tell you whether or not a particular thread is missing an expected incoming connection.  If it turns out that the problem is due to the non-blocking I/O, then you may need to disable non-blocking I/O when you expect an incoming socket or implement a control that keeps track of how many incoming sockets you expect and continues until that goal is met.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is possible that a certain thread might not receive any connection requests. The input file is used to determine who is supposed to do what.


At the moment, if I enable non-blocking client, the program will generate errors regarding sockets not yet being connected. Also, if I disable non-blocking server, the program will just hang because each thread is awaiting for connections and no one is reading the input file. I also tried to implement a selector, but the problem was that the loop there block at the select() call.

Comment: One options is to programmatically enable/disable blocking I/O (using configureBlocking method) depending on when you expect to receive a message: initially set the socket to non-blocking.  Once you reach a case where you expect an incoming response, change it to blocking until the connection is received.  Once received you can change it back to non-blocking until it is needed again.  An alternative is to this switch is to only listen for a connection when you expect one to come in rather than performing a connect on every iteration of the while loop.